# Enable hotspot / tethering on Nexus 5X + 6P without a subscription plan? Root and no Root

Tags: root-access, wifi-hotspot, tethering, nexus-5x, nexus-6p

Is there a way to enable hotspot / tethering for the Nexus 5X and 6P even if you don't have a subscription plan for it? How do you do it via rooted phone and a non-rooted phone?

Comment: I use Verizon with my 6p... and I have no issues turning on the mobile hotspot... and I dont have the plan for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only "fix" that has worked for me thus far.

I switched from the Nexus 5 to the 6P yesterday and discovered that my grandfathered unlimited data plan was of not much use now because the Wifi hotspot functionality has to be activated through the carrier on the 6P. Wifi Hotspot tethering worked just fine on the Nexus 5.

At least I can use my hotspot, but this pop-the-sim-card-out work around will get old fast... Oh well :/

Answer (score 13):

**With rooting**

(tested on **6.0.1** on 2016-05-10  and **7.1.1** on 2017-02-09)

- Flash TWRP 3.0
- Root your system with superuser.zip
- Download ES file explorer
- Remount /system to be read-write
- Goto /system and edit build.prop
- On the last line enter: `net.tethering.noprovisioning=true`
- Then, `adb shell settings put global tether_dun_required 0`
- reboot

**Without rooting**

You only need your sim tool and the phone.

1. open the sim tray but don't take out the sim card.
2. push the sim tray back in the phone.
3. wait 4-5 seconds and then activate hotspot in the settings->more->tethering

Works for Verizon and AT&T. I have not tested this on any other carriers. This works by turning on the hotspot while the phone is provisioning. If you attempt to do this too soon or too late you will trigger the subscription check.
You will need to perform this everytime you want tethering if you turn tethering off or reboot the phone.

Comment: It's unnecessary to open the SIM card tray. You can make the same thing work by enabling AirPlane mode, then disabling it, and quickly moving to turn on the hotspot. I just did this and am now online :)

Comment: Does this still work for you @JohnZeller? I just tried it and it doesn't work (I turned off airplane mode and clicked the tethering option within 2 seconds).

Comment: The "airplane mode" method doesn't work for me, on Nexus 6P

Comment: Airplane mode method, SIM is recognized too quickly. Doing the popped-sim method works 100% of the time after "5 Mississippi" -- +1

Comment: The SIM card method stopped working for me last week. Tethering starts, and then after a few seconds turns back off once the SIM is done registering. Does anyone have any other ways to do this un-rooted?

Comment: Confirming the root method works on Sprint Nexus 6 7.1.1 (N6F27E)

Comment: Confirming that this method works on a Nexus 5X on Verizon in 2019.

Answer (score 0):

This also appears to work with the Moto X Pure Edition using Straight Talk.  Slightly modified steps, though.  Eject SIM tray, turn on tethering, Push in tray.